# Does CORS prevent CSRF?

Tags: cors, csrf

I have a website on github pages and a contact form, the backend of which is on a different domain.
Received data from the form is sent remotely to another domain. CORS policy is used here. Everything seems to be ok, but I am interested in a question related to CSRF, how to implement it in this case and is it necessary at all? Does CORS prevent CSRF?

```
const form = document.getElementById('contact_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const send = {
    name: document.querySelector('input[name=name]').value,
    email: document.querySelector('input[name=email]').value,
    subject: document.querySelector('input[name=subject]').value,
    message: document.querySelector('input[name=message]').value
// token: document.querySelector('input[name=token]').value// 
//When the backend was on the same domain as the contact form, I checked the //token this way.
  };
  const jsonString = JSON.stringify(send);
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const action = form.getAttribute('action');
  xhr.open('POST', action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
  xhr.onload = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
    };
  xhr.send(jsonString);
});
```

```
// if(empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
//     $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
//   };
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dynamicportfolio.com');
header("Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, POST");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, origin, content-type');
 $object = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $request = json_decode($object);

if(isset($request)){
//if($request->token == $_SESSION['token']){
     //We load data into the database.
   //};
};
```

Form:

```
<form class="wrapper" id="contact_form" action="http://form/configs/form.php" method="POST">
            <div class="app-form-group">
              <input class="app-form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"  maxlength="50">
            </div>
            <div class="app-form-group">
              <input class="app-form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="test@gmail.com"  maxlength="50">
            </div>
            <div class="app-form-group">
              <input class="app-form-control" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="50">
            </div>
            <div class="app-form-group message">
              <input class="app-form-control" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" >
            </div>
<div>
             <!-- <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $_SESSION['token']; ?>">-->
            </div>
            <div class="app-form-group buttons">
              <button type="submit" class="app-form-button">Send</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it does not. The same origin policy should prevent it, but it is a bad joke from security perspective. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy I am not certain what it allows, a few years ago all it did is sending the request but blocking the response at certain scenarios. So you were able to POST with someones session cookie and if there was no CSRF token or extra questions like the previous password required, then you were able to change someones password for example. You need to use CSRF token. As of CORS it relaxes the same origin policy by allowing access to the response from certain origins and allowing more exotic methods like PUT and DELETE with preflight.